# Convert Binary string (80 Characters) to Data in Swift

Tags: swift, string, nsdata

I have binary string which has 80 characters. 
e.g. **11100000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111** (80 bits i.e. 10 bytes)
and would like to convert it into Data

One way i tried

```
    let binStr = "11100000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
    let splittedStr = binStr.split(by: 8) // which splits the string 8 character lenght
    var dataVal = Data()
    for strs in splittedStr {
        var val = strtoul(strs, nil, 2)
        let binaryData = Data(bytes: &val, count: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)
        dataVal += binaryData 
    }
```

but looks like dataVal returning wrong value. Is it the right way to do it ?

i used this to split the string :

```
extension String {
    func split(by length: Int) -> [String] {
        var startIndex = self.startIndex
        var results = [Substring]()

        while startIndex < self.endIndex {
            let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: length, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex
            results.append(self[startIndex..<endIndex])
            startIndex = endIndex
        }

        return results.map { String($0) }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Your code would work on little endian platforms.

Comment: @koen i would like to convert binary string to Data

Comment: @OOPer I found the problem with my understanding. I was comparing byte array from Java with Data in Swift. I thought those are same.                 byte[] bval = new BigInteger("11100000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111", 2).toByteArray();                                                                                     
 Java, byte array returns array of Signed Int whereas Swift Data consist of Unsigned Int (if i m not wrong). I think you have answered it here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/100185 which helped me understanding the things.